# WooCommerce bulk change product type with mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

When importing products with WpAllImport, all of our products are stored as variable products, even if they don't have any variations. We need these to be stored as single products.

How can we change all the product type to single for all products that doesn't have any variations using MySql? We're having trouble with the query.

Hoping some WooCommerce experts can help us out with this one..

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your query so far?

Comment: please share your MySQL query or code that you have tried.

Comment: It's deleted, was way off :(

Answer (score 2):

First from MySQL take back up of your database, then you can get id of your product type from below query:

```
select term_id from wp_terms where name='variable' // assume return 4 as result

select term_id from wp_terms where name='simple' // assume return 2 as result
```

By above query you can get id of both product type.which need to use in update query mentioned below.

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id)
SET wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '2' where wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '4'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this needs to be done for about 16.000 products. We need something more automatic :)

Comment: custom query from MySQL would be specific i guess, or you can prepare script by PHP file base on above query.make sure to get back up before any action steps :)

Answer (score 0):

First get all variable products with a loop. Using each product post Id, get the available variations. If there are no variations for the product. Then change each to simple.

```
  <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
        'product_type' => 'variable'
                );
            $products = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
     $variations = array();
$id = the_ID();
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $id
);
$variations = get_children( $args );

    if(sizeOf($variations) == 0){
    wp_set_object_terms( $id, 'simple', 'product_type' );
    }
                endwhile;
            } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would change all the variable product to simple products. We only need to change the variable products which doesn't have variables.

Comment: Didn't know that was a stipulation. I fixed it to where it only changes products with no variations. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again. When running your code I get this error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function the_post() on null

Comment: No errors this time, but nothing changed in the database as far as I know.

Comment: I was grabbing the variations wrong within the loop. Use a echo to see if it's reaching the if that changes the variable to simple

Answer (score 0):

```
-- update WooCommerce variable products without variations to simple
--1
CREATE TABLE PPCD_EDI_TEMP_UPDATE
SELECT r.object_id
FROM wp_posts wp 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON wp.ID = r.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta SKU on SKU.post_id = wp.ID and SKU.meta_key = '_sku' -- SKU.meta_value as sku
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta PRICE on PRICE.post_id = wp.ID and PRICE.meta_key = '_price' -- PRICE.meta_value as price
LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_custom_lookup PCL on PCL.product_id = wp.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wpv ON wp.id = wpv.post_parent AND wpv.post_type != 'attachment'
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_type' 
AND t.name = 'variable' 
and wpv.ID is null; --test for one product, replace ; with the following: and SKU.meta_value = '10001894';
--2
UPDATE wp_term_relationships 
SET term_taxonomy_id = (select term_id from wp_terms where name='simple')
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = (select term_id from wp_terms where name='variable') AND object_id IN (select object_id from PPCD_EDI_TEMP_UPDATE);
--test
SELECT SKU.meta_value as sku, PRICE.meta_value as price,
wp.id AS 'Product Id', 
wpv.id AS 'Variant Id', 
wp.post_title as parent_title, 
wpv.post_title as variant_title, 
wpv.post_excerpt 
FROM wp_posts wp 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON wp.ID = r.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta SKU on SKU.post_id = wp.ID and SKU.meta_key = '_sku' -- SKU.meta_value as sku
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta PRICE on PRICE.post_id = wp.ID and PRICE.meta_key = '_price' -- PRICE.meta_value as price
LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_custom_lookup PCL on PCL.product_id = wp.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wpv ON wp.id = wpv.post_parent AND wpv.post_type != 'attachment'
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_type' 
AND t.name = 'variable' 
and wpv.ID is null;
```